# How do touch attacks work in Microlite20?

Tags: spells, attack, touch-attacks, microlite20

How do touch attacks work in the Microlite20 system?  For example, on page 7 the description of the 1st Level Arcane Spell "Shocking Grasp" reads as follows:

> Touch delivers 1d6/level electricity damage.  Max 5d6.

Is this damage intended to be automatic in Microlite20?  Or did I miss the rules that cover touch attacks in the game?  Obviously, the game is based on the Open Gaming License/Standard Reference document.  I could certainly adapt a 3.5 rule, but I would like to know what was intended by the RAW.

Thanks!

Useful Links for anyone unfamiliar with the system:
[Microlite20 Homepage](http://microlite20.net)
[SystemReferenceDocument.org Microlite Download page](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=134:microlite20)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not automatic. To hit with a magic attack, you roll as usual and apply your **magic attack bonus** to the roll. Your magic attack bonus is defined in § *Combat*, as your MIND bonus plus your level.

By RAW you need to hit your target's full AC—but the whole point of Microlite20 is to define some minimal sensible rules so that you can riff off them seamlessly and effortlessly, so go ahead and take the extra fraction of a second to calculate a Touch AC for the target by whatever method seems reasonable, if you want.